# NUnit test adapter: why is single test executed multiple times?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit, restsharp

I have a very basic test example using NUnit 3.0.1, NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework 2.0.0 and RestSharp 105.2.3, written in C# in VisualStudio 2015. When running tests with NUnit test adapter, my test is executed 2 times instead of 1. Seems like 2 test adapters are running in parallel. What could be the reason? I expect it to be run only once, of course. Thanks in advance!

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using RestSharp;
using System;

namespace Project1.Tests
    {
        public class Test1
        {
            [Test]
            public void GetTest()
            {
                var client = new RestClient("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/");
                var request = new RestRequest("CUSTOMER", Method.GET);
                var queryResult = client.Execute(request);
                Console.Write("result: " + queryResult.Content.Length);
                Assert.IsTrue(queryResult.Content.Length > 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished
A test with the same name 'Project5.Tests.Test1.GetTest' already exists. This test is not added to the test window.
========== Discover test finished: 2 found (0:00:00,1950195) ==========
------ Run test started ------
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started
Loading tests from     E:\Testing\RestVS\Project5\Project5\bin\Debug\Project5.dll
Run started: E:\Testing\RestVS\Project5\Project5\bin\Debug\Project5.dll
result: 4672
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is finished
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started
Loading tests from  E:\Testing\RestVS\Project5\Project5\bin\Debug\Project5.dll
Run started: E:\Testing\RestVS\Project5\Project5\bin\Debug\Project5.dll
result: 4672
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is finished
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:06,0725361) ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using NUnit Adapter v2 if your NUnit version is 3.0.1?

Comment: I'm just using latest available versions

Comment: The latest one is 3.0.8 https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d

Answer (score 0):

you have both the Visual Studio extension and the NuGet package of the NUnit Test Runner.

Removed the Test adapter from the Visual studio extension.
On the Tools menu, click Extension Manager.
In Extension Manager find The Test adapter and click the disabled or uninstall.